# node-sass / node-gyp problems

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm working on a project which give me [this](https://github.com/lucasbusso/Pelurqueria_Proyecto) file, and I can't install the dependencies of the gulpfile.js. This is the error console. I need help please.

I already tried to install node, node-sass, node-gyp, but I always have the same problem, and I tried other solutions that I'd seen in the forum.

```
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.       
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution 
issue
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map- 
resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. 
Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map- 
url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may 
use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See 
https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.     
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see 
https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low- 
severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 
3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not 
receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe 
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js 
rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   
'C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\Ejercicios\\Peluqueria_Proyecto\\node_modules\\node- 
gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.6.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError 
(C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F 
(C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E 
(C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at 
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at 
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at 
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError 
(C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F 
(C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E 
(C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at 
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at 
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at 
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python39\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print 
"%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Ejercicios\Peluqueria_Proyecto\node_modules\node- 
sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-09T22_20_25_927Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Don't use node-sass

`node-sass` has been deprecated. Instead you will have to use its new version, which is the `sass` package.

You can uninstall the old and install the new one with this command

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install `Additional Tools for Nodejs` to fix that in `Start Menu > Node.js > Install Additional Tools for Node.js`

but as the error says

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print 
"%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
```

try reinstalled the python , or you can upgrade to Python 3.10